# Angular2 Managing nested subscribes

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the following code skeleton in angular2 (ts) :

```
a() {
  return callService1.do(
    z => { 
      callService2.subscribe(y => console.log("a callService2")) 
      console.log("callService1")
    }
  )
}


b() {
   a.subscribe(
     x => console.log("b subscribe callService1")
   ) 
}
```

as a result, I do have :

```
"callService1"
"b subscribe callService1"
"a callService2"
```

I would really have expected to have `"a callService2"` before `"b subscribe callService1"` and I am not sure to understand that result. What could I do to enforce having `callService2.subscribe` done before my `a.subscribe` in b() ?

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions don't run in the order they appear in your code. "callService1" and "b subscribe callService1" run when Service1 has some data. "a callService2" won't run until Service2 has some data.